# how to package installed packages?

Tags: dpkg, packaging, deb

Is there anyway to package the installed software on the system?

I mean without going to`/var/cache/apt..` and without downloading anything else, can i use a `dpkg` command to make a packages from all installed software on my system?

So i can take those packages, put them on a CD, and install them on another system without grabbing files from the cache or using AptonCD.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use dpkg-repack to accomplish this.

1. Install [dpkg-repack [image: Install dpkg-repack]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dpkg-repack) and [fakeroot [image: Install fakeroot]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/fakeroot) (to avoid being root to repackage). Or from the terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dpkg-repack fakeroot
   ```
2. Repackge installed package

   ```
   fakeroot -u dpkg-repack <package name>
   ```

And you'll find the package in the current directory.

Note that any changes on the system on the package after it has been installed will be reflected in the repackaged version!

Comment: Is there any way to repack all dependencies in a folder? Because I can't use output of this package and don't have internet to install with `gdebi`

Comment: @Daniyal you may need o write custom script for that

Comment: Thanks, Can I write with `apt-rdepends` and bash script?

Comment: @Daniyal, yes you can but `apt-rdepends` just emulates dependence resolving, may be better to use `debfoster` instead.