# how to save packages installed in one virtual machine and install them in another virtual machine in ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, latex, vmware-workstation

I have been using (rather say trying to use Ubuntu 19.04) in a virtual machine.
There have been n number of problems.
Like [Unable to get IP on my Ubuntu 19.04 virtual machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171585/unable-to-get-ip-on-my-ubuntu-19-04-virtual-machine) and [changing username for ever in 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185077/changing-username-for-ever-in-19-04) 
I installed Latex packages in it. 
I want to use TexLive in it due to some research work.
But due to various problems I faced in this virtual machine I will delete this one. I want to know is it possible to use the downloaded texlive packages in one installation to install in another instance. The download was approximately 1 Gb and bandwidth is a problem for me. I can not again and again download packages.
If this is possible please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two alternatives:

1. if the packages are still in /var/cache/apt/archives you can copy them from there to the same directory in the new machine. Then `apt` will tell you it does not need to download them.
2. if they are no longer there, say because you did an `apt-get clean` for example, then you can repack them to recreate the deb packages and then move those to the new machine and reinstall them. Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309527/how-to-package-installed-packages).